# Load video from link? iOS

Tags: ios, video

I used to be able to play videos in iOS 3 and half of iOS 4 until 4.2 or something like that until they changed a lot of the API's and messed up the way I play videos. So can anyone share their code to load a video from a link and play it?
Also would it be possible to make the done button not work on the MPMoviePlayerController?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should post your code, so someone could tell you where the problem is. Or just have a look in the changelog?

Comment: I actually found working code it was from a tutorial on the web! Thanks anyway!

Comment: then please close your question or post an own answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633080/ios6-and-mpmovieplayercontroller-black-view/12638243#12638243 refer this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found working code it was from a tutorial on the web!

Comment: What and where is the tutorial? :)