# iOS6 and MPMoviePlayerController - Black View

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

I have a MPMoviePlayerController that plays a video embedded within a View. This worked perfectly on iOS5/5.1 etc... but since upgrading to iOS6 this has stopped working and now the view is just black. Does anyone have any ideas or similar issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one......

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ddd" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMediaTypeMusicVideo;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: Stange, code is the same, with the exception of setting the controlStyle, but it's got it working so, thanks!

Comment: @dhaya : same problem i had but this code works for me thanks. but there is no audio ? any idea?

Comment: @Astanienohpi I know it sounds obvious, but have you ensured your device is not set to mute?

Comment: This answer is not really correct because it uses MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController. The former is supposed to be used when you want to present a modal fullscreen view. The question asked about "video embedded within a View".

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController  *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:yourURL];  [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)];  moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
            moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
            [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
            [moviePlayer play];

Answer (score 5):

I was access to the same problem, and finally finding that the key line "[player prepareToPlay]" missing. in iOS5 it does no matters, but in iOS6 it lead to a black screen;

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, MPMediaTypeMusicVideo is defined as MPMediaType, below is the definition:
   MPMediaTypeMusicVideo   = 1 << 11, (2048)

Is it the undocumented thing?