# How to play Video-Audio on iOS 6?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am playing videos and audio in my iOS app using **AVAudioPlayer** for Audio files (.mp3 files) and **MPMoviePlayerViewController** for videos files (.mp4 files).

It works fine on iOS 5 and lower versions.

But in my iPad ( iOS 6) it doesn't work. It plays video with no audio. Of course it doesn't play audio at all.

Please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633080/ios6-and-mpmovieplayercontroller-black-view

Comment: I prefer using AVFoundation when playing media on iOS. AVPlayer can play both videos and audio. Read up on  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html . Thats not an answer to your question, just a tip for the future :)

Comment: Since iOS 6 the mute switch will also mute apps, did you check if the mute swoth is turned off.

Comment: Thanks ali59a for quick reply, I'll check it.

Comment: thanks Mikael for your response, I'll read it

Comment: Thanks rckoenes for your reply, I have checked the mute switch but I didnt get it where it is?

Comment: Hi @ali59a, I m using the same code provided on the link you have given. It works fine in iOS 5 but it doesn't work on iOS 6. It only displays video without an audio.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes, I found the settings for mute switch, by turning it OFF it works great ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since iOS 6 the mute switch will also mute apps, did you check if the mute swoth is turned off.

To force playback if the device is muted you could do the following:

```
NSError *error= nil;
if ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error setting audio session: %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];

if(setCategoryErr || activationErr)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ Error: Could not activate silence mode. %@ %@", self, setCategoryErr, activationErr);
}
```